# ZScore calculation in python different value then expected

Tags: python

Working on the dataset, trying to scale data with zscore.

Zscore formula is (value - mean) / std , in that case since our first observation is 10000 in the column Avg_Mthly_Spend, while mean is  4850  and std is 2877.59545.

As per the formula zscore should be 1.78968, but when using zscore library not sure why the zscore calculated  1.886498 using Zscore package in python notebook.

See the attached image which described the dataset and it scaled dataset after applying zscore. the zscore evacuated as 1.886498 instead of 1.78968.

See the image from the jupyter notebook.

[Jupyter Notebook snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CBeE.png)

Comment: Hello @YambdaJamba. Could you please add the relevant pieces of code to the question? Maybe reduce the problem to a minimal example that demonstrates the issue and add sample data? Please, feel free to also check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am using standard describe method of Panda to show the means and standard deviation. There are only 10 records in the data ,  

It may be describe function using different way to calculate the mean or standard deviation which could be different from the way zscore is calculating. I am not challenging either but would like to understand why it is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Panda describe method calculates the std considering data as sample not entire population, while in zscore while calculating standard deviation it consider data as total population where by default ddof is zero. Setting degree of freedom to 1 allows it to consider as sample and also match the result with describe method.

custDataScaled=custDataAttr.apply(zscore , ddof = 1)

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on how you calculate the std, since `std = sqrt(var)` it depends on `var` (variance).

In the variance formula you can either divide by `n` or `n-1` (depending on what estimator you want); I assume that is the difference

Comment: I am using standard describe method of Panda to show the means and standard deviation. There are only 10 records in the data ,  

It may be describe function using different way to calculate the mean or standard deviation which could be different from the way zscore is calculating. I am not challenging either but would like to understand why it is different.

Comment: Then you'll need to check how pandas calculate their std